# Grails Spock Unit Test - What is "1 *" and why "too few invocations"?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I see the following code within a Unit Test for a controller that I have inherited from others:

```
  when: "When the controller executes a registration"
      controller.index()

    then: "the signup should show registration again"
      1 * controller.cService.getRegions() >> [] 
      1 * controller.dService.chkAvail(_) >> "AVAILABLE"
      1 * controller.uService.createUser(_) >> { a-> throw new RuntimeException("Roll me back!")}
      1 * controller.pService.registerPayMethod(_) >> { cc-> true }
      view == "/signUp/su"
```

I understand the basics of spock unit tests, but I don't understand these `1 *` lines.

I am also getting multiple errors such as:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Too few invocations for:

1 * controller.cService.getRegions() >> []   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

Comment: the error says, that that method was not invoked, while you expected it to invoked once

Comment: @cfrick Thanks, this is the kind of thing that happens when a developer hasn't read the basics. So, in this way we can validate that specific methods were invoked a certain number of times. If you want write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are telling Spock, that the method in question has to be invoked exactly once (`1 * controller.cService.getRegions() >> []` means, `getRegions` of this service has to be called once (`1 *`) and will return an empty list (`>> []`)).  But it hasn't.  This is what the error message is telling you (`0 invocations`).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out below example:-

```
def "List Invocation Calls Test"() {
    given:
    List list = Mock();
    when:

    list.add(5)
    list.add(15)
    list.add(25)

    then:
    3 * list.add(_)
}
```

Comment: Can you please also explain your example?